# как отправку методом $.ajax post изменить на $.ajax post с промисами

Tags: javascript

как отправку методом $.ajax post, изменить на  $.ajax post  с промисами(.then) чтобы еще выдавало   например console.log("error") если файла не нашло

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'data.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {jsonMy: arr , fileName: 'data.json'},

    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(msg) {
      text.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr);
    }
});
```

Comment: `$.post('data.php', { filename: ...}).done(function(msg){...}).fail(function(){console.log('err)})` такое что ли?

Comment: что значит `$.ajax post с fetch`?

Comment: @Grundy мб имеется в виду, не только отправка запроса, и но и получение результата с его обработкой?

Comment: ну или без него но с $.ajax с промисами перепесать

Comment: чтобы был .then вверху это отправка массива в файл ,я еще хотел переписать с промисами что бы ошибку выдавало если нету этого файла

Comment: что типо function ajax(options) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax(options).done(resolve).fail(reject);
  });
}

Comment: ajax({
  url: someURL,
  type: 'post',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: JSON.stringify({
    something: something,
    anotherthing: anotherthing
  })
}).then(
  function fulfillHandler(data) {
    // ...
  },
  function rejectHandler(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // ...
  }
).catch(function errorHandler(error) {
  // ...
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример с `$.ajax`:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: 'data.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    jsonMy: arr,
    fileName: 'data.json'
  },
  dataType: 'html'
}).done(function() {
  text.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr);
}).fail(function() {
  console.log('error');
});
```

Вот пример с `fetch`:

```js
fetch('data.php', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/html',
    'Content-Type': 'application/html'
  },
  body: {
    jsonMy: arr,
    fileName: 'data.json'
  }
}).then(function() {
  text.innerHTML += JSON.stringify(arr);
}, function() {
  console.log('error');
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое !!!